# Javascript or Form validation when code refers to other forms

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

The following uses Form buttons to mark photographs as different qualities. If Quality 1 or Quality 2 or chosen the php code should fire. However if "delete" is chosen instead of assigning a quality I would like an "Are you sure" validation before executing the script. I don't want the validation unless the delete button is pressed. As the form code even changes css I don't want the code to run at all if delete is pressed until OK on "Are you sure" has been confirmed.
I tried some methods but the form ran instantaneously, probably because of the `$('form').on('click', 'input[type="submit"]', function(e) {` line. I stripped my attempts from this as it just confuses the issue. I would like the syntax for the validation on this. Any help greatly appreciated. (I stripped the code for the images as that is not needed in the example).

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
    $('form').on('click', 'input[type="submit"]', function(e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: "mycode.php", 
            data: $(this).parent().serialize(),
        });
        var clicked = $(this),
            imageName = clicked.data("image");
        clicked.removeClass("c_off").addClass("c_on");
        $('input[type="submit"]').each(function() {
            var self = $(this);
            if (!clicked.is(self)) {
                if (self.hasClass("c_on") && imageName == self.data("image"))
                    self.removeClass("c_on").addClass("c_off");
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <input name="num" type="hidden" value="101">
    <input name="shw" type="hidden" value="1">
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="c_off" data-image="67">
</form>

<form>
    <input name="num" type="hidden" value="101">
    <input name="shw" type="hidden" value="2">
    <input type="submit" value="Quality A" class="c_on" data-image="67">
</form>

<form>
    <input name="num" type="hidden" value="101">
    <input name="shw" type="hidden" value="3">
    <input type="submit" value="Quality B" class="c_off" data-image="67">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zeog65js/1/

```
$(function() {
    $('form').on('click', 'input[type="submit"]', function(e) {
        if($(this).val() == 'Delete') {
            if (confirm("Delete it?")) {
              doAjax($(this));
            } 
        } else {
            doAjax($(this));
        }

        e.preventDefault();
    });
    function doAjax(that){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: "mycode.php", 
            data: $(this).parent().serialize(),
        });
        var clicked = that,
            imageName = clicked.data("image");
        clicked.removeClass("c_off").addClass("c_on");
        $('input[type="submit"]').each(function() {
            var self = $(this);
            if (!clicked.is(self)) {
                if (self.hasClass("c_on") && imageName == self.data("image"))
                    self.removeClass("c_on").addClass("c_off");
                }
        });
    } 
});
```

Comment: That just needed a little tweek. data: $(this).parent().serialize(), needed to be data: $(that).parent().serialize(), - Got it working now. Cheers!

Comment: Oh, sorry, i've missed it. Glad to help you! Accept please the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `submit` handler on the form instead, so that you can prevent sending the form, do every validation you want **prior** to the actual submission of the form:

```
$('form').submit( function(e) {
  // Prior to the submission, check if we are in
  // the delete button and raise the "Are you sure" button
  if (validations)
    return false; // This will prevent the submission
  else {
    // Run your PHP code
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: "mycode.php", 
      data: $(this).parent().serialize(),
    });
  }
});
```

More info https://api.jquery.com/submit/